# Mouse dead zone that makes it impossible to click?

Tags: 11.04, mouse

I have upgraded my ubuntu from 10.11 to 11.04.
The problem is, there is a horizontal mouse dead zone, I can not click in that area.

My laptop is Acer Aspire 5920G

But, when my friend installing ubuntu 11.04 in Vaio laptop, he gets the same problem with me, there is a mouse dead zone in the same area.

Anyone can help me to fix it?

[image]

I can not click on that zone (highlight in image)

Comment: Where is this dead zone? Can you please update your question with a screenshot?

Comment: Log out, log in again - is the zone still there? If not, then it's a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/755459).

Comment: @aendruk I have updated with image

Comment: Sorry, I think [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/709461) one is the right bug. Anyways, it's known, it's being worked on, and probably a fix is going into a stable release update.

Comment: For me, no more dead zones adding the xorg-edgers ppa and upgrading from it.

Answer (score 7):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/709461) in Compiz, unfortunately it's not fixed yet but when it is it will be rolled out in an update.

Answer (score 1):

just to inform I have the same problem, a little (~20cm x 1cm horizontal) rectangle on the screen is affected
is not always there appear after a while I don't know why

1. I don't use unity
2. I on ubuntu 11.04
3. I have compiz working with emerald 0.9.4
4. using gimp I clicked the screen until I surrounded the area then I did a red rectangle

[image]