# Button click issues in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, mouse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mouse dead zone that makes it impossible to click?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44118/mouse-dead-zone-that-makes-it-impossible-to-click)

This is kind of a weird problem. My main concern is whether it's just me or whether others are experiencing the same issue, in which case it'll likely be fixed much faster.

In short, sometimes I am unable to click on buttons and hyperlinks. I hover over them and they don't change appearance at all. I click them and get no response. Not all buttons, not all the time, and not with any kind of predictability that I've been able to gauge.

I had a file properties window open just prior to starting this thread and the *Close* button wasn't working. The *X* button in the window chrome worked fine. And accessing the *Close* button via the keyboard worked fine, too. Indeed, that's how I've worked around this issue when it crops up thus far - with the keyboard.

I've just opened the file properties window again to take a screenshot whilst hovering over the button, and now the *Close* button works. That's how sporadic this issue is - it's infuriating.

Does anyone know if this is an already reported issue? I googled but couldn't find anything of note.

Thanks

Comment: refer http://blaze-core.com/issuesresolutions-with-ubuntu-11-04/ it is explaining common issues with ubuntu 11.04 and its resoulution